# In science fiction, which planet with lifeforms has the largest gravitational force?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, gravity

I've just started reading [Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_(novel)) and Gaal Dornick has landed on Trantor for the first time and notices that:

> The air seemed thicker here, the gravity a bit greater, than on his
> home planet of Synnax...

This prompted me to wonder, **what is the highest gravity planet mentioned in science fiction that has lifeforms?**

I am specifically asking about planets with solid surfaces, and I am referring to the gravitational force at the surface.

Comment: There have been some stories with zeppelin-style lifeforms that float around in the atmospheres of gas giants, would you count those or are you asking only about planets with solid surfaces?

Comment: Plenty of examples here; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Heavyworlder

Comment: I remember some pulp comic postulating a giant planet hosting "mini-humans" (the small size making easier for them to bear the high gravity).

Comment: Do they count as lifeforms if they've converted themselves into computer entities and built themselves a neutronium dense computer/planet to live in?

Comment: To whoever keeps closing this as "too broad" - [the community consensus so far on Meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/why-was-this-question-closed) is that it is NOT too broad. Please respect that.

Comment: For clarification, does it HAVE to be a planet? The highest gravity *environment* in fiction which has lifeforms that I know of happens to be the surface of a star.

Comment: @DVK Less people agree that it shouldn't be closed than it takes to close the question, so I think it would be fairer/more correct to say that there's discussion about whether or not the question should be closed, not that community consensus is that it shouldn't be.

Comment: I think the question needs a little clarification, to say whether you mean the gravitational force at the surface or the overall gravity (i.e. the mass) of the planet. A very large but low-density planet like a gas giant may have a fairly low surface gravity (insofar as a gas giant _has_ a surface), but a higher mass than a denser planet with higher surface gravity. For example, Uranus has 86 times the mass of the Earth, but only 90% of the surface gravity.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - at least 7 people agree - among those that frequent Meta (which is a subset of people on the main site).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist "Less people agree that it shouldn't be closed than it takes to close the question" Source for that claim?  5 people voted to reopen already.  At least 8 people (including myself) agree with my answer on meta that it should not be closed.  AFAIK, only 5 are required to close a question. I agree it may be early to call it a consensus, but so far more people are in support of it being open than closed; not the other way around.

Comment: Are we restricting this to hard SF, or at least to planets that would be reasonably plausible under the known laws of physics? Because if not, I'm sure there's some old pulp story somewhere that mentions a planet with a thousand or ten thousand or a million times Earth's gravity, whatever struck the author as a suitably impressive large number.

Comment: @Beofett When I wrote that comment there were less than five upvotes on your meta answer, so less than it takes to close a question. Since DVK was using that as the basis for "community consensus", that's what I was looking at; hard to factor in the reopen votes because voting is anonymous so we can't see where the overlap is. There's also six upvotes on the competing meta answer, so it's obviously not the clear cut issue DVK was trying to make it out as.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I believe there were 4 up votes when you wrote that comment. 4 up votes, plus myself, since I cannot up vote my own answer, is still enough to reopen. But yes, I already conceded that I agree "consensus" was a bit premature.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Sounds like Dan Simmons' Endymion to me, right?

Comment: @Zommuter - I was thinking of Iain Banks' "The Algebraist" (though the creatures there weren't actually zeppelin shaped), but there are [lots of others](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LivingGasbag).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Probably Hexanerax 2 in *Childhood's End* by Arthur C. Clarke, given that Robert L. Forwards's *Dragon's Egg* is a neutron star not a planet. Here's how it is described:

> The planet was absolutely flat. Its enormous gravity had long ago crushed into one uniform level the mountains of its fiery youth—mountains whose mightiest peaks had never exceeded a few metres in height. Yet there was life here, for the surface was covered with a myriad geometrical patterns that crawled and moved and changed their colour. It was a world of two dimensions, inhabited by beings who could be no more than a fraction of a centimetre in thickness.

That's pretty much all we know about it—it's a throwaway vision, not the setting for any of the novel.

(Hal Clement's Mesklin from *Mission of Gravity* is an obvious contender, but its gravity is a mere 3 g at the equator where the known life is, and 665 g at the poles, which is probably still less than Hexanerax 2 as described.)

Comment: I was considering Dragons Egg, but yes it was a neutron star. However, if the OP was interested in lifeforms evolving in extremely high gravity it's definitely a recommended read. IMO it's one of the best books I've read.

Comment: I'm going to ignore that physics would never allow for a massive, yet completely flat celestial body. But, if the celestial body is completely flat, could it really be considered a [planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAU_definition_of_planet)?

Comment: I don't think it's intended to be two-dimensional, which would make no sense, but rather an exact sphere that's locally flat.

Comment: @MikeScott It would also have to be small and consistently dense to achieve flatness, rather than large. Im not convinced true flatness would occur though.

Comment: Why would it have to be small?  The larger it is, the larger the radius, and the smaller the curvature.

Answer (score 25):

I'll venture that the winner is none other than our old favourite; **Krypton**. Without focusing on specific numbers, the surface gravity on Krypton would have to be **tens of thousands of times heavier than Earth** to meet the description below.

Bronze-age Superman writer [Elliott S Maggin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliot_S._Maggin) (formerly Senior Writer for DC comics) described Krypton as a "**failed star**" and a "[black-hole planet](http://www.starwinds-howl.com/print.html)" whose mass was so great that conventional rockets wouldn't even allow you to leave the surface:

> Jelassian had a habit of assigning nicknames like "The Big
>   Rettubzzash," but pirates in general had an avuncular nickname for
>   Krypton.  **It was "The Black-Hole Planet."  Nothing ever left.  It was
>   as dense as a newborn star and as dark as the pit.  From a more
>   conventional planet with crusted frozen oceans, life should at the
>   very least have reflected so much that astronomers in nearby systems
>   might at first have mistaken it for a star.  It was so heavy that
>   space itself contracted around it.**  A dull green glow, the backwash of
>   starlight that collected in its atmosphere, reflected downward to
>   streak Krypton's daytime sky with red-shifted luminous clouds and
>   light its nights with a phosphorescent pink.  The light radiated from
>   every horizon.  The days were barely brighter than Krypton's nights.
>
> It took an enormous expense of energy to launch anything from the
>   world's surface.  Even a nuclear-powered vessel designed to accelerate
>   across lightyears of space needed to tap the thermal energy of the
>   planet's underground in order to trigger a reaction big enough just to
>   escape Krypton's terrible attraction.  Even on a world whose
>   population's profligate use of energy had actually slowed the planet's
>   self-destruction, Jor-El realized that his use of so much power in one
>   burst would certainly attract attention.  He gave himself the chance
>   to make the only test of his prototype starcraft.

---

If we're just looking at [heavyworld sci-fi](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HeavyWorlder) in general, then you can't got far wrong with [Flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_(novel)) by Stephen Baxter. The main characters are tiny humans living *inside* the surface of a neutron star rather than merely living on the surface, like the wimpy lifeforms in [Dragon's Egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon's_Egg)

Comment: The gravitational force inside the star would be *less* than on the surface, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user14111 - Only assuming a perfect spherical object at rest. If it was spinning, the gravity a few milimeters below the surface would be slightly higher

Comment: @user14111 don't forget the pressure

Comment: The neutron star in *Flux* definitely was spinning. The vortexes formed in the neutron superfluid were a major plot point.

Answer (score 9):

I don't remember the name of the story; but you didn't ask that.

I believe that the answer might be ***Jupiter***. 
Isaac Asimov wrote a short story in his robots series about the "ZZ" line of robot,
which was designed to travel to the surface (!) of Jupiter. 
Three of them traveled there in a non-airtight spaceship
(rather than try to build something that could withstand the atmospheric pressure). 
They encountered creatures that were sufficiently advanced
that they attacked the robots with weapons (although not effectively).

Comment: On a related note, the [hydrogues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_of_The_Saga_of_Seven_Suns#Hydrogues) inhabit gas giants and the [faeros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_of_The_Saga_of_Seven_Suns#Faeros) inhabits stars in The Saga of Seven Suns.

Comment: The title is ["Victory Unintentional"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44199). There is a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Unintentional) for that story.

Comment: Jupiter is also inhabited in Arthur C. Clarke's **2010: Odyssey Two**, although it's pre-sapient life.

Comment: And by sapient life in Timothy Zhan's [*Manta's Gift*](http://www.amazon.com/Mantas-Gift-Timothy-Zahn/dp/081258032X)

Comment: The question has been edited to exclude Jupiter. Planets with solid surfaces only.

Comment: @MikeScott: Gas giants are theorized to have a solid surface, if you go down far enough.  However (going back to the question), the gravity at the surface might not be super-high, since most of the planet is above you (as gas and liquid).  So, incredible pressure but not incredible g.

Comment: In Asimov's story the surface of Jupiter was solid.

Comment: However, Jupiter's "surface" is downright benevolent with regards to gravity, compared to the other entries here...

Answer (score 4):

By far not the one with the highest density (looking at Mike's and Richard's answers here), but [Perry Rhodan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan) issue #16, "Die Geister von Gol", was about a planet of 916g surface gravity, making it a #3 entry at the time of posting. ;-)

Rhodan and his crew navigated the surface with tracked multi-purpose vehicles ("Shifts"), which needed their anti-gravs (usually used to let them fly) running at max output just to keep them mobile (and not crushing the crew).

I am not sure if you could call the beings they encountered "life forms" (and neither were the protagonists), as they seemed to be energy-beings, but they were attracted by the vehicle's shields (reacting to stimulus), and drained their power supply, growing in size in the process (feeding, growth), so let's call them "life".

---

The highest gravity planet to bear *human* life in the PR universe would be Oxtorne, a 4.8g world. A shipwrecked crew of emigrants managed, with the help of genetic engineering, to adapt to the harsh environment of their world within four generations.

Comment: +1 I remembered this age old issue but would for the life of me not have been able to remeber its name. :)

Comment: I admit I cheated and looked it up on [Perrypedia](http://www.perrypedia.proc.org/wiki/Hauptseite). Since I was pretty sure this was during the search for ES, I looked up the [title list](http://www.perrypedia.proc.org/wiki/Die_Dritte_Macht_%28Zyklus%29), and when my eyes fell on the title, I knew I had found just the one. ;-) That's also where I found the *exact* gravitation, I just remembered it was 900-ish.

Answer (score 1):

Not as much gravity as a neutron star, but Iain M Banks's [The Algebraist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Algebraist) features a race called the Dwellers who float around inside of gas giants throughout the galaxy.

ZanLynx mentioned in the comments the Hades Matrix from Alastair Reynolds's [Revelation Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_Space_universe) series, a neutron star that was somehow converted into an impossibly dense and powerful computer so that a long-dead race could go on living as programs within the matrix. So they're not exactly life forms in high gravity, but maybe it still counts.

Comment: And not sure if it counts but I believe in one of Banks' novels there's a mention of a culture that "transcended" by moving their minds into a super-dense neutronium-type computer planet. Maybe the reference is in Matter? Or maybe Surface Detail.

Comment: @ZanLynx I don't remember that from the Culture novels but it sounds a lot like the Hades Matrix from Alastair Reynolds's [Revelation Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_Space_universe) series.

Comment: You know, I believe you are correct. Reynolds it is.

Answer (score 0):

First Mesklin popped my mind from "Starlight" by Hal Clement. It is a true planet (not a neutron star like Hexanerax2) and it has a solid surface (unlike the aforementioned gas giants), but it has a size of a smaller gas planet and a shape so distorted that the strenght of the gravity on its equator is slightly different than on its poles.

Comment: Actually even Earth has gravity gradients on its surface, but that's probably not what you mean. ;-)

Comment: I think in the novel it was 2.5 times larger gravity on the poles.

Comment: 2.5 != "slightly different" ...

Comment: A few misconceptions here. First, Hexanerax 2 is a planet and not a neutron star -- perhaps you're confused by my answer giving Hexanerax 2 also mentioning (to dismiss it as not a planet) the neutron star called Dragon's Egg. Second, Mesklin's variable gravity is not caused by its shape -- rather both its distorted shape and its variable gravity are caused by its extremely high rotation. Third, the gravity at Mesklin's poles is over _two hundred_ times as strong as at the equator (660G versus 3G), not "slightly different".

Comment: @MikeScott - You might be right. I have read "Statlight" when I was a kid.

Comment: Rather more than slightly. Iirc it's 3G at the equator and 700G at the poles.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Baxters Flux tells a story about a "human" civilization living on a neutron star. Not really humans, but made by humans to be able to live on the neutron star.

Answer (score -1):

Xelaya, the evil planet 20g from "The Orville." "The Orville" Alara Kitan girl is super evil because she and the Lamberts attacked Khitomer while posing as Romulans. Worf didn't know this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include any relevant quotes from the source material, particularly any that specified the degree of gravity on Xelaya.

Comment: "Canon" estimates of Xelaya's gravity, based on speculation from dialogue, are 3-4g.  This, however, is inconsistent with the thermos demo.  https://www.facebook.com/TheOrville/videos/xelayan-gravity-episode-3-season-2-the-orville/2241634269451632/

Answer (score -2):

recent: A Soldier's Duty by Jean Johnson. Protagonist, Ia, is from planet Sanctuary. It is a heavy world (defined as >1.5g) with a gravity of 3.28g.

Comment: 3.28g is only a fraction of what was posted in previous answers. The question isn't looking for "what are all the heavy worlds".  It's looking for the **heaviest**, so posting an answer that is lighter than existing answers is rather counter productive.